# the function "fgetc ()" does not work properly in a While

Tags: c, file, codeblocks

I wrote a little program that is supposed to read the contents of a file character by character but what the code does is that it jumps each time a character as if it escapes a caracters each time and I don't understand why

and i dont know what to do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, age = 18;
    char strind[] = "Himou";
    FILE *file = NULL;

    file = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
        if(file != NULL)
        {
            do
            {
                printf("%c", fgetc(file));
            }while(fgetc(file) != EOF);

            fclose(file);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("the file couldn't be open");
        }

   return 0;
}
```

the file exists and contains "Hello World !!Your name is Himou and your age is 18", so thats what i expected but the actual result "HloWrd!Yu aei io n oraei 8"

Comment: How many times per iteration do you want to read a character? How many times per iteration are you actually reading a character?

Comment: oh, i see i doing the reading tow times per iteration. and thats why it's not working, Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it jumps each time a character as if it escapes a caracters each time
>
> ```
>        do
>        {
>            printf("%c", fgetc(file)); <<< here you read and print a character
>        }while(fgetc(file) != EOF);    << here you read again a character and lost it
> ```

yes this is true, because you ask for that, see comments I added in the code above

> i dont know what to do

probably you want something like that to write all the read characters :

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
  putchar(c);
```

Comment: A program always does what the programmer has asked it to do. This is a tautology.

Comment: @n.m. including when the programmer doesn't know what he (really) asked ^^

Comment: Of course. Hence a real answer would explain what the programmer really asked and *why* it's different from what they wanted to ask.

Comment: Hey sorry I didn't see stuff on the far right, I'm browsing from my phone.